# ExecuteNonQuery returns what int value

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

What values `ExecuteNonQuery` returns if `update`, `insert`, `delete` are success, at the same time when they were failed?

Comment: This question is clearly about programming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the number of rows affected.

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command.

Answer (score 4):

You might find the following reference material handy, [`SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .

To quote directly:

> Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected.

So...

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

So either the number of rows affected by the command(s) or -1.

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteNonQuery` returns count of affected rows

Answer (score 0):

[The number of rows affected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For the most time propably 1.