# C#: Procedure or function has too many arguments specified - Because dataset is interfering

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am getting the error in the subject when I try to perform an update from the C# code.

I tested the code with hard coded values, and it works.

These are the hard coded values, passed to the update method from the button click, doing it like this, works:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    spe.ActionTypeID = 1;
    spe.ResultTypeID = -1;
    spe.ResultMessage = "";
    spe.StorePageID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["StorePageID"]);
    spe.SPPreambleID = 16;            
    spe.Title = txtTitle.Text;
    spe.SEOTitle = txtSEOTitle.Text;
    spe.ParentStorePageID = -1;
    spe.Meta = txtMeta.Text;
    spe.Image = null;
    spe.ImageLink = null;
    spe.Blurb = null;
    spe.RegionID = 1;
    spe.Footer = txtFooter.Text;

    count = spd.StorePage_Update(spe);

    if (count > 0)
    {
        Session["StorePageID"] = null;
        Response.Redirect("~/StorePageList.aspx");
    }
}   

public int StorePage_Update(StorePageEntity sp)
{
    try
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "cud_UpdatePage";
        cmd.Connection = con;

        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActionTypeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = sp.ActionTypeID;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResultTypeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = sp.ResultTypeID;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResultMessage", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sp.ResultMessage;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StorePageID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = sp.StorePageID;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SPPreambleID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = sp.SPPreambleID;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = sp.Title;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEOTitle", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = sp.SEOTitle;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParentStorePageID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = sp.ParentStorePageID;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Meta", SqlDbType.Text).Value = sp.Meta;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sp.Image;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageLink", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sp.ImageLink;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Blurb", SqlDbType.Text).Value = sp.Blurb;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegionID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = sp.RegionID;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Footer", SqlDbType.Text).Value = sp.Footer;
        count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                
    }            
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Write("StorePage_Update: problem with command:" + cmd + "e=" + e);
        Console.Out.Flush();
        throw new Exception("StorePage_Update: problem with command:" + cmd, e);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (con != null) { con.Close(); }
    }
    return count;
}
```

But when I change from hard coded values to values from the web form, and database, then I get the "Procedure or function has too many arguments" error.

This is how the code looks with db, and web form values:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    spe.ActionTypeID = 1;
    spe.ResultTypeID = -1;
    spe.ResultMessage = "";
    spe.StorePageID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["StorePageID"]);

    ds = spd.StorePage_Select_One(spe.StorePageID);     

    spe.SPPreambleID = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].IsNull("SPPreambleID")) ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SPPreambleID"]);          
    spe.Title = txtTitle.Text;
    spe.SEOTitle = txtSEOTitle.Text;        
    spe.ParentStorePageID = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].IsNull("ParentStorePageID")) ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ParentStorePageID"]);       
    spe.Meta = txtMeta.Text;
    spe.Image = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].IsNull("Image")) ? null : ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Image"].ToString();
    spe.ImageLink = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].IsNull("ImageLink")) ? null : ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ImageLink"].ToString();
    spe.Blurb = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].IsNull("Blurb")) ? null : ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Blurb"].ToString();
    spe.RegionID = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RegionID"]);
    spe.Footer = txtFooter.Text;

    count = spd.StorePage_Update(spe);

    if (count > 0)
    {
        Session["StorePageID"] = null;
        Response.Redirect("~/StorePageList.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Session["StorePageID"] = null;
        Response.Redirect("~/StorePageList.aspx");
    }
}
```

I tried commenting out each one of the values and test, but the error did not go away.

Then I tested with hard coded values leaving this line in the code:

```
ds = spd.StorePage_Select_One(spe.StorePageID);
```

And it then gave me the same error with hard coded values.

I think that this is what is causing the error, but I need to have a way to get the values that is why I added the dataset and call to the method: **Page_Select_One**

I ran SQL Profiler and I can see what the problem is, the StorePageID parameter is passed twice.

Here is the results from profiler:

```
exec cud_UpdatePage
@StorePageID=20,
@ActionTypeID=1,
@ResultTypeID=-1,
@ResultMessage=N'',
@StorePageID=0,
@SPPreambleID=17,
@Title=N'sax store',
@SEOTitle=N'sax seo',
@ParentStorePageID=-1,
@Meta=N'text',
@Image=default,
@ImageLink=default,
@Blurb=default,
@RegionID=1,
@Footer=N'text'
```

**UPDATE**

Figured out the error. 
I added cmd.Parameters.Clear();
Before adding the parameters and now it works.

Can someone explain to me how can I correct this problem?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Your code is very hard to follow.  What line is throwing the error?

Comment: if you are using `AddWithValues` then you really don't need to pass the DataType because the Database will resolve it `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` try using `cmd.Parameters.Add` if you are going to pass the datatype in this method.. also do a MSDN Search on all of the overloads for both methods `AddWithValue & Parameter.Add Method` also I would personally move the `try` an wrap the code around the actual `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` also where are you declaring the Out Parameter to return the `count` this can be done in a much cleaner way..

Comment: `count = spd.StorePage_Update(spe);` in this line what are you expecting the return value to be from the Update Query..? `the number of rows affected..?` please read this post and it's reference links for a better understanding of what `ExecuteNonQuery` does. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21602070/executenonquery-returns-what-int-value

Comment: the line that gives the error: count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
the error: "Procedure or function has too many arguments specified"

Comment: How about the actual procedure code? Do you have nocount on? And what is the point of the if(count > 0) part? It does the same code either way.

Comment: I can post the sp code, but like I said, this only happens when I execute it from the C# app.

Comment: The <if(count>0), was a typo I left in the code accidentally.

Comment: my problem is that when I have the dataset within the button click method, it interferes with the update as it may be passing more than it needs. I just do not know why is doing this.

Comment: I do not have a no count on on the SP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the error. 
I added cmd.Parameters.Clear(); 
Before adding the parameters within the Update method, and now it works.